# Ejecutar un applet

Tags: java, applet

Soy nuevo en java y al tratar de ejecutar el siguiente código, me muestra un error en las librerías que dice

> No main class found

y no me ejecuta nada

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;

/**
 *
 * @author Aprendiz 2
 */
public class JavaApplication1 extends Applet {

public void paint (Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("Hola mundo",50,25);
    // TODO code application logic here
}

}
```

[image: Aquí el error]

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es con las librerías como piensas.

el error no main class found significa que no hay nada que correr, y esto es porque los applets tradicionalmente se corrían mediante un plugin instalado en el navegador.

Para correrlo desde un [jframe](/questions/tagged/jframe) te recomiendo hacer las siguientes modificaciones:

1. Cambia `extends Applet` por `extends JApplet` que es un tipo de panel
2. Modifica tu código de pintado para llamar primero a super ( evitas fondo transparente del JFrame )
3. Agrega un método main
4. crea un nuevo `JFrame`
5. Agrega una instancia de `JavaApplication1` al `JFrame`

Tu código quedaría asi:

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import static javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

/**
 *
 * @author Aprendiz 2
 */
public class JavaApplication1 extends JApplet {

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString("Hola mundo", 50, 25);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cargando un applet en un JFrame");
        JavaApplication1 miApplet = new JavaApplication1();
        miApplet.init();
        frame.getContentPane().add(miApplet);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```